# xtab breakpoints and avoid breaks in multicols

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, multicol, xtab, columnbreak

I am trying doing a tex in two columns and the content are majority tables, I want the format of the next image.

Title in One columns and then table in the left columns until the end and then continues in the right column, and where this ended, start the next table. (Like Office Word works)
[image: Concept]

> Question here

But the problem is, I want define where the table A can break, I want 5 rows together. or avoid one alone row in the second column. (That is easy only set the last 5 rows unbreakable)

So, this is easy with `Longtable` but multicols doesn't works as i want. I am searching something like `\\*` `\nopagebreak` but in `xtab` or `supertabular`.

Or another package that works.

> Code

Here is my code.

[image: Example Error]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xtab,multicol}
\usepackage[margin={2cm,5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}

\makeatletter
\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\newcommand{\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols}{%
  \renewcommand\newpage{%
    \if@firstcolumn
      \hrule width\linewidth height0pt
      \columnbreak
    \else
      \mcnewpage
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{centering}
    \Huge\textbf{{MENS}} \\
\end{centering}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

    \begin{centering}
        EVENT 1
    \end{centering}

    \TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols
    \xentrystretch{-0.1}
    \tablehead{COL A & COL B & COL C & COL D \\ \hline}
    \begin{xtabular}{l|l|c|c}
        GROUP 1 & & &    \\ 
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
        GROUP 2 & & &    \\ 
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
        GROUP 3 & & &    \\
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
        GROUP 4 & & &    \\
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\ 
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
        GROUP 5 & & &    \\
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\ 
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\
        GROUP 6 & & &    \\
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
        GROUP 7 & & &    \\
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
    \end{xtabular}

    \begin{centering}
        EVENT 2
    \end{centering}

    \TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols
    \tablehead{COL A & COL B & COL C & COL D \\ \hline}
    \begin{xtabular}{l|l|c|c}
        GROUP 1 & & &  \\ 
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
        GROUP 2 & & &    \\ 
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
        GROUP 3 & & &    \\
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
        GROUP 4 & & &    \\
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\ 
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
        GROUP 5 & & &  \\
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\ 
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
        GROUP 6 & & &    \\
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
        GROUP 7 & & &    \\
        A & a & INFO & 1 \\
        B & b & INFO & 2 \\
        C & c & INFO & 3 \\
        D & d & INFO & 4 \\
        E & e & INFO & 5 \\
        F & f & INFO & 6 \\
    \end{xtabular}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```